# symfony accessing form values iteratively

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I want to access values of a form from a template. Poor symfony documentation and google are not helping. Assume I don't know the names of the fields. I don't want to do a `$form->getObject()->getFieldName()`

**SOLUTION**: Ok. I got this. `$form->getValues()` does a pretty good job for me.

Comment: You should write the solution as an answer to your comment and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I got this. $form->getValues() does a pretty good job for me.